# Sum of Squares Program in C with equation z = x^2 + y^2

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a program that finds and writes out all pairs of positive integers x and
y such that x^2 + y^2 = z. I want to Prompt the user for the value z. x and y
can either or both be zero. For example, if z is 25, then x and y are:

0, 5; 3, 4; 4, 3; 5, 0.

If no such x and y are found, the program writes out “None Found”. The program doesn't search through
all possible integers to find x and y. For a given value of z it can stop
searching for x when x^2 > z. (And the same for y.)
I need to expect z to be zero up to a value called INT_MAX.

This is what I have so far:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<limits.h>

int main()
{   
 int x,y,z;

 printf("Enter a value for Z: \n");
 scanf("%d",&z);

 z = x*x + y*y;


 for(x = 0; x*x < z; ++x)
 {   
    printf("%d",&x);
 }

 for(y = 0; y*y < z; ++y)
{
printf("%d",&y); 
 }   

}
```

My issue is that I'm trying to write some sort of loop that will start both x and y equaling zero and then increment them up to form all the different possible combinations of x and y to get whatever the user inputs for Z. Here, I have them in two different for loops. I'm not sure what to do, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `z = x*x + y*y;` this line seems to be pointless. Also, probably you want nested loops.

Comment: "all pairs of positive integers x and y" --> "all pairs of non-negative integers ..."

Comment: For more optimized algorithms, see, e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/a/4720397/8033585

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<limits.h>

int main()
{   
    int x, y, z, zx, found;

    printf("Enter a value for Z: \n");
    scanf("%d", &z);


    found = 0;
    for(x = 0; x*x <= z; ++x)
    {
        zx = z - x*x;
        for(y = 0; y*y < zx; ++y);
        if (zx == y*y)
        {
            found += 1;
            printf("%d, %d;\t", x, y);
        }
    }

    if (found == 0)
        printf("No solutions have been found");
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you!

Comment: When `z` is large, `x*x < z` can `int` overflow which is undefined behavior (UB) and can lead to an infinite loop.  `for(x = 0; x || x < z/x; ++x)` does not have that problem.  Similar weakness with `y*y < zx`.

Comment: @chux Thanks for comments! I fixed `<=` point. The overflow issue I'll leave here as comment: my intention was to provide an outline to fix broken logic in OP example. Your comments are valid and should be taken in account by OP.

Comment: The inner loop doesn't actually have to start at 0. Without restriction we can assume X >= y and then any solution we find, we just also print the mirror solution (swap x and y) unless both numbers are equal.

Comment: Also, as a note @JohnDaniewicz, there are other more performant algorithms to solve this problem, see, e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/a/4720397/8033585 My code here is the simplest fix for what I thought was OP _intention_.

Comment: @IngoBürk Yes, that is true and I was thinking about the same thing. Usually people want _unique pairs_ and not swapped values (in addition to original). But I will leave optimization to OP (or, you can post your own answer).

Comment: I actually just noticed that the code does not give me 5,0 also as an answer, which would just be the mirror of 0,5. Yet it gives me both 3,4 and 4,3.

Comment: @JohnDaniewicz Fixed in the last edit: the innermost loop should have had _strict_ inequality.

Comment: Good, but an explanation in English would be welcome